# Php не видит расширение

Tags: php, postgresql, apache

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе Postgres, у меня стоит Apache 2.4, Php 5.6.40, в php.ini раскоментил extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll, но вывод phpinfo показывает, что данного расширения нет.

Comment: Apache пробовали перезапускать после этого?

Comment: да , не помогло

Comment: длл то в наличии и той же разрядности, как и все остальное? лог посмотрите.